# How to set Django Admin to show all User's attributes in his User Profile tab?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, django-users

I'm working on a `Django` project. I have two types of members (user profiles) - Customer and Translator. I would like to see those profiles in a Django Admin including it's User attributes like `username`, `surename` etc.

Now, when I create let's say UserTranslatorProfile called `Thomas`, I can see his name, username etc. in `Users` in `Auth` in `Django Admin` and the other attributes which belongs to it's profile in `UserTranslatorProfiles` which is very uncomfortable. (In `UserTranslatorProfile` I can see which user it is but I can't see his attributes and can't change them).

The two profiles are here:

```
class UserTranslatorProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language)

class UserCustomerProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

And they are of course registered in `admin.py`

So the question is: Is it possible and if, how to see all `User` and `UserProfile` attibutes by clicking on `UserProfile` in `Django-Admin`?

Answer (score 3):

Add a [`ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) for `UserTranslatorProfiles` and add the `username`, `email` and other related fields into the `fields` attribute.

`ModelAdmin` are put in the `admin.py` file and they further customize the way models are displayed in the admin.

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from myproject.myapp.models import UserTranslatorProfiles # Import your model

    class UserTranslatorProfilesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        fields = ('username', 'email, ) # Enter full list of fields here

    admin.site.register(UserTranslatorProfiles, UserTranslatorProfilesAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks Abu, could you elaborated it little more please? I don't know how and where to add ModelAdmin. I've checked for example this url: http://patrick.arminio.info/additional-admin-views/ but it did not help.

Comment: Hm, It does not work. Exception Value: 
Unknown field(s) (first_name) specified for UserTranslatorProfile. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class UserTranslatorProfileAdmin. But I think that first_name belongs to each User so it should be correct.

Comment: I've added this into admin.py: class UserTranslatorProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('first_name',)

admin.site.register(UserTranslatorProfile, UserTranslatorProfileAdmin)

Comment: oh, you used `user` as a foreign key. This would not work for a foreign key. You need to subclass User. `class UserTranslatorProfile(User)`

Answer (score 1):

Just need to set ModelAdmin and register it with admin site

`step 1:`  create a admin.py in your application if not exist.
`step-2:`  import your model you want to show on admin site.
`step-3:`  Create a admin model and register it with admin site.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.myapp.models import Author #import your model
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      fields = ('name', 'title', 'view_birth_date')# define-fields


admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin) #now register your custom-admin model
```

for more
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

Comment: `//` does not work as single line comment in Python. You have to use `#`. Example: http://ideone.com/mzkkT1

Comment: This does not work. I've added this into my admin.py and added just one attribute into fields - 'first_name' which is definitely present in built-in User. But it does not work: Exception Value: Unknown field(s) (first_name) specified for UserTranslatorProfile. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class UserTranslatorProfileAdmin.

Comment: From where it should know that I want this attribute, when it does not belong to the Profile but to the User?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is more difficult than it needs to be/should be. Without an inline admin, the admin add/change forms are only built to edit one model.

If you're able to change your user model, you can accomplish this by creating your own custom User object that inherits from User. Then, in settings.py, set AUTH_USER_MODEL to your new model. Note that this should be done before data has been input, and your first migrations have been done (so you'd need to start fresh.)

If you're unable to do so, I can think of two other directions you could take:

Easier: Create an inline admin for the User object, and register that to your translation object. Then you'll have a single row in an inline admin at the bottom of the page, which can be used to edit the User. I hate this from an end-user UX perspective, but it could get the job done.

Neater: Create a custom form, add fields that correspond to those that you'd like to edit in the User model, and then in the form's clean and save methods, validate/save the methods of the underlying User object. For example, create the form fields "tra_username", "tra_firstname", "tra_password"... Then, in the form's save method (after validation), do this for each field

```
UserCustomProfile.user.first_name = form.cleaned_data.get("tra_firstname")`
UserCustomProfile.user.save()
```